# sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel returns 501 error on serivces.odata.org

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am trying to create an OData model in SAP UI5 this way:

```
new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");
```

but I am getting a 501 not implemented error! 
could you please check what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it, the service is not *really* CORS-enabled. I have the same problem with my own examples here, as soon as I am not using some kind of proxy, I get this error.
The reason behind it is that when you send a complex request to the service, you'll autmatically have a so-called preflight request sent by your browser (before the actual GET) which is not a GET-Request, but an HTTP OPTIONS request.
All the odata.org sample services return a 501 error at the moment for such requests.
You can e.g. use the simpleProxyServlet which is shipped with UI5, or of course any other proxy which would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as your **browser will refuse this request due to same Origin Policy**. Here is what you should do:

- **Deploy the app on the same server or domain as the service** that you want to call, so that both resources are in the same origin (if possible)
- **Disable the same-origin policy in the browser** for local testing. Run Chrome by running Chrome with the following command:
  [your-path-to-chrome-installation-dir]\chrome.exe
  --disable-web-security --user-data-dir. Make sure that all instances of Chrome are closed before you run the command. This allows all web
  sites to break out of the same-origin policy and connect to the
  remote service directly.

  -> Don't do this in your productive app as it imposes a security risk.
- **Using a proxy**

The following documentation should help you understand this more and implement:

- [Conncting with oData Service](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109)
- [Request failing due to Same-Origin Policy sharing(CORS)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5bb388fc289d44dca886c8fa25da466e.html)

Answer (score -1):

Please use "proxy/http/services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc", I think it's solve your problem!